What is the difference between Dropout(1.0) and stop_gradient?
Consider these two architectures:
prev_layer -> dropout 1.0 -> next_layer (output layer)
prev_layer -> stop_gradient -> next_layer (output layer)

As gradients flow from the output layer to the input, both must produce the same behavior where prev_layer weights will not be updated, so what is the difference?
I have verified it with this code:
input_layer = Input(shape=(1,))
prev_layer = Dense(32, activation='relu')(input_layer)
dropout_layer = Dropout(.99999)(prev_layer)  # This is effectively disabling the layer
output_layer = Dense(1, activation='linear')(dropout_layer)
model_dropout = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
model_dropout.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

input_layer = Input(shape=(1,))
prev_layer = Dense(32, activation='relu')(input_layer)
stop_gradient_layer = Lambda(lambda x: tf.stop_gradient(x))(prev_layer)
output_layer = Dense(1, activation='linear')(stop_gradient_layer)
model_stopgradient = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
model_stopgradient.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

Train them:
before_train_dropout = model_dropout.layers[1].get_weights()
before_train_stopgradient = model_stopgradient.layers[1].get_weights()

X_dummy = np.random.rand(5, 1)
y_dummy = np.random.rand(5, 1)

model_dropout.fit(X_dummy, y_dummy, epochs=50, verbose=0)
model_stopgradient.fit(X_dummy, y_dummy, epochs=50, verbose=0)

after_train_dropout = model_dropout.layers[1].get_weights()
after_train_stopgradient = model_stopgradient.layers[1].get_weights()

# Is array equal
print('weight')
display(np.array_equal(np.array(before_train_dropout[0]), np.array(after_train_dropout[0])))
display(np.array_equal(np.array(before_train_stopgradient[0]), np.array(after_train_stopgradient[0])))
print('bias')
display(np.array_equal(np.array(before_train_dropout[1]), np.array(after_train_dropout[1])))
display(np.array_equal(np.array(before_train_stopgradient[1]), np.array(after_train_stopgradient[1])))

Returned:
weight
True
True

bias
True
True

So, when should I use between Dropout(1.0) and  stop_gradient?

Although they do they same thing during a backward pass, they act quite differently during a forward pass.
A stop_gradient layer passes the input tensor as-is to the output.
A dropout layer drops some elements with a probability of rate. If rate=1, then all outputs are zero.

Is this affecting the back propagation performance of multi-task learning from another output layer, such as the b task? Since Dropout(1.0) sets all outputs to zero, which means the y_pred_a during training will become 0. Hence, the model will calculate the overall loss as the (y_target_a - 0) + (y_target_b - y_pred_b). While stop_gradient returns y_pred_a as-is, hence the model will calculate unstable overall loss like (y_target_a - y_pred_a) + (y_target_b - y_pred_b), where y_pred_a value will vary depending on performance of b task?

@CitraDewi Yes, that would affect training performance. If there's some layer before the stop_gradient/Dropout(1) layer which could be trained, and there's no path between that layer and the output that preserves gradients, then it won't be trained. The Dropout layer will additionally inhibit training of later layers, as it will act differently during training and inference.

So, Dropout(1.0) is equivalent to dot product of any tensor value to the zero?

@CitraDewi Yes, that's right.
